# Is there a way to type isActive function of React router NavLink in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

```
 <MenuItem
          component={NavLink}
          to={to}
          key={text}
          selected={selectedNavIndex === index}
          **// compiler complaining about match of any type**
          isActive={match => {
            if (match) {
              onNavSelectHandler(index);
              return true;
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          }}
        >
          <StyledListItemIcon>
            <StyledIcon as={icon} width={width} />
          </StyledListItemIcon>
          {text && isOpen && <ListItemText primary={text} />}
        </MenuItem>
```

I am trying to use the **isActive** function of react-router in the typescript project but I can not type it correctly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `isActive` prop of the react-router-dom `NavLink` component is defined like this:

```
export interface NavLinkProps<S = H.LocationState> extends LinkProps<S> {
    isActive?<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string }>(match: match<Params> | null, location: H.Location<S>): boolean;
...
```

[source link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4f1c6741c37cac2861be4b1970b02b6e9add4c63/types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts#L79)

You can import this `match` type (which is weirdly lowercased) and use it like so:

```
import {NavLink, match as Match} from "react-router-dom";
```

```
<MenuItem
...
  isActive={(match: Match | null) => {
    if (match) {
      onNavSelectHandler(index);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }}
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and also how can we type for the second parameter (location) of the isActive function?

Comment: import { Location } from “history”.  The generic <S> describes the state property of the location.